# Execute SET statement in EntityFramework context before call Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have the following code script:

```
using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
{
    var records = context.GetData();
}
```

I need to adjust some SQL Server "SET STATEMENT ON|OFF" before call context.GetData()

```
using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
{
    // EXAMPLE =======> SET DATEFORMAT dmy
    context.?????? // How?

    var records = context.GetData();
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED");
```

Comment: I tried with "set dateformat ymd" but this change was not remain for the session, that is, the instruction context.GetData() does not take the new date format.

Comment: @JaimeCamargo Add `context.Database.Connection.Open();` at the beginning of the `using` block, then `ExecuteSqlCommand` will have effect.